# Z-index not rendering properly in Safari - works in all other browsers

Tags: css, webkit

I have a nav menu that slides into view from the right side of the screen once the hamburger icon is clicked. It works correctly in Chrome and Firefox - basically when triggered it takes up 50vw and fills the screen vertically. However in Safari it seems as if the z-index is not behaving correctly because the menu appears to be buried underneath the other elements of the page and ultimately not visible at all.

I've tried adjusting the z-index of a variety of elements to see if that was the simple fix and it has proven to be something more complicated. I have read a few forums that suggested including "-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);" but unfortunately that doesnt seem to work either. If you inspect the sidebarMenu element in Safari you can see that it is in the correct position, it is just not rendering correctly.

Below is a link to a codepen - I am missing some styles on this so the positioning isnt quite right but it effectively shows the general functionality that I am looking for. When opening this link in Safari you can see that the sidebarMenu does not appear to be rendering at all.
https://codepen.io/rmann20/pen/EzbeaV

sample code:

```
<div class="header">
      <hr class="nav-rule">
      <div class="nav-container">
          <div class="nav-logo-container">
            <a href="index.html"><img class="nav-logo" src="images/nav_logo.png"></a>
            <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
              <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
                <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
                <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
                <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
              </label>
              <div id="sidebarMenu">
                <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
                  <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms & Suites</a></li>
                  <li><a href="packages.html">Packages</a></li>
                  <li><a href="dining.html">Eat & Drink</a></li>
                  <li><a href="events.html">Meetings & Events</a></li>
                  <li><a href="weddings.html">Weddings</a></li>
                  <li><a href="experiences.html">Experiences</a></li>
                  <li><a href="neighborhood.html">Neighborhood</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="sidebarMenuInnerSecondary">
                  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="history.html">HISTORY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                  <li><a href="press.html">PRESS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="careers.html">CAREERS</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
          <img class="nav-tagline" src="images/nav_tagline.png">
          <a class="nav-reservation-button" href="" target="_blank">RESERVE NOW</a>
      </div>
      <hr class="nav-rule">
    </div>




.header {
        display: flex!important;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        box-shadow: none;
        background-color: #f5f4f0;
        position: fixed;
        height: 110px!important;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 10;
        justify-content: space-between!important;
    }

    .nav-container {
        display: flex;
        height: 79px;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    .mainInner{
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .mainInner div{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 3em;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1.25px;
    }
    #sidebarMenu {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        width: 50vw;
        margin-top: 42px;
        transform: translateX(50vw);
        transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
        background-color: #f5f4f0;
        overflow: scroll;
        padding: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
        z-index: 10000!important;
    }
    .sidebarMenuInner{
        margin:8px;
        padding:0;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
        list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebarMenuInner li a{
        color: #3d3936;
        font-family: 'QuincyCF-ExtraBold', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 3.2em;
    }

    .sidebarMenuInnerSecondary {
        margin-top: 60px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .sidebarMenuInnerSecondary li {
        margin-top: 14px;
        margin-bottom: 14px;
    }


    input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    input[type=checkbox] {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebarIconToggle {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 48px;
        right: 40px;
        height: 28px;
        width: 28px;
    }
    .spinner {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #3d3936;
    }
    .horizontal {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 3px;
    }
    .diagonal.part-1 {
        position: relative;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
    }
    .diagonal.part-2 {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 3px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transform: rotate(135deg);
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
        transition: all 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
        margin-top: -9px;
    }

    .nav-logo-container {
      width: 260px;
      margin-left: 40px;
    }
```

I dont get any errors and everything else seems to be working correctly, can't figure out why it's not showing at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!